# Violation of proportional hazard assumption with big sample size - how to correct for it?

Tags: survival, stata, proportional-hazards

I am looking at a sample of about 95,000 firms in Switzerland and I want to find out if having an external auditor (such as PwC, KPMG, EY) reduces the likelihood that a firm goes bankrupt. In Switzerland, smaller companies can choose if they want to have their accounts audited or not, i.e. they can 'opt-out' from having an external auditor.

So far I have looked at this mainly by using logistic regression models with bankruptcy (0/1) being the dependent variable. However, I would like to corroborate my results with survival analysis techniques.

I have come up with the following basic Cox proportional hazard model in Stata:

```
stcox bOptingOut lncapital i.firmCanton i.industryCode
```

- `bOptingOut` is my treatment/non-treatment variable (1 = opting-out, i.e. no auditor; 0 = no opting-out, i.e. financial statements are audited)
- `lncapital` is the natural logarithm of the firm's paid up capital in Swiss Francs (corresponds practically to USD)
- `firmCanton` is an indicator variable to control for the canton/state in which the firm is domiciled
- `industryCode` is an indicator variable to control for industry effects

In principle, I was quite happy with the model as the coefficients are highly significant and the direction of the effects appears reasonable.

```
. stcox i.bOptingOut lncapital i.firmCanton i.industryCode, nolog

         failure _d:  event == 3
   analysis time _t:  (date1-origin)
             origin:  event==1
  enter on or after:  event==1 time td(01jan2008)
  exit on or before:  event==3 time td(31dec2018)
                 id:  id

Cox regression -- Breslow method for ties

No. of subjects =       94,319                  Number of obs    =     161,050
No. of failures =        9,683
Time at risk    =    299931461
                                                LR chi2(44)      =     4529.30
Log likelihood  =   -106232.09                  Prob > chi2      =      0.0000

------------------------------------------------------------------------------
          _t | Haz. Ratio   Std. Err.      z    P>|z|     [95% Conf. Interval]
-------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
1.bOptingOut |   1.425763   .0464468    10.89   0.000     1.337574    1.519766
   lncapital |   .8598573   .0107152   -12.12   0.000     .8391103    .8811172
```

Then I turned to to testing the proportional hazards assumption. First, I did some graphical checks and plotted the hazard and survival functions as well as `stphplot` and `stcoxkm`. Things do look quite okay (see picture below).

[image]

Afterwards, I performed the test based on Schoenfeld residuals (`estat phtest`) and get a Prob>chi2 value of 0.0000.
Based on this, the proportional hazards assumption is clearly violated.

Currently, I have two main questions:

a) Does my data set really violate the proportional hazard (PH) assumption? Or is this simply due to the big sample size I have?

b) If the PH assumption is really violated, is it okay to use a lognormal parametric model instead [`streg ..., dist(lognormal)`]?
Based on AIC/BIC that would be the best of the parametric models.

EDIT:
Below I attach a plot of the Schoenfeld resiudals (Stata command `estat phtest, plot(bOptingOut)`)
[image: Schoenfeld Residuals]

Comment: I don't know Stata, but couldn't you output a plot of Schoenfeld residuals like in `plot.zph` in `R` ? Another good way to visualize if the PH assumption is violated is to split the model on several periods (`survSplit` function in `R`) and see if HR are very different, is that doable with Stata ? There indeed is a probability that your Schoenfeld residuals test is significant because of your big sample size but no one can tell without investigation

Comment: Hi Dan Chaltiel, I edited the post and added a plot of Schoenfeld residuals.